# Android 14 SDK preview: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set up the Android SDK preview in Android Studio using [this guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk#groovy).

Despite following the guide and using:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
    }
}
```

When I try to install this on an emulator running UpsideDownCake, I just get:

```
04/02 10:33:44: Launching 'app' on Pixel XL API UpsideDownCake.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\Me\StudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\apk\devpro\debug\app-devpro-debug.apk'
The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I don't know why it thinks that "The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level" because the device is on UpsideDownCake.

Any ideas?  I've tried rebuilding project, and invalidating caches and restarting... no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you might be using `Android Gradle Plugin` version greater than `4.2.0` because the setup you are currently using is for `Android Gradle Plugin` version `4.2.0` or below. Therefore, first check your `Android Gradle Plugin` Version. This can be found in the `Project Structure` of your project. If your `Android Gradle Plugin Version` is greater than `7.0.0` then replace

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
    }
}
```

with

```
android {
    compileSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
    }
}
```

Comment: D'oh... at first I did think that it should be `"UpsideDownCake"` because my gradle plugin version is greater than `7.0.0` but using that just gave me a gradle sync error straight off.  My mistake was thinking that it was still `compileSdkVersion`/`targetSdkVersion` but in fact it should be `compileSdkPreview`/`targetSdkPreview`.

Comment: If it solves your query then mark it as answer so it could be helpful to others

Comment: It should work ...

Comment: @GhazanfarAteeb thanks I know how stackoverflow works

Comment: compileSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.autosmarts.audit"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
        versionCode 19
        versionName "2.2.4"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

still error  The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.